# Adicionar d-block aos inputs automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu preciso que, quando remova o foco do input, verifique se o campo ainda está vazio, se sim, um "d-block" é inserido na calsse da div com id "blurName". A solução postada resolve o problema, mas são muitos campos. Alguma ideia para reduzir tal trabalho?

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <label for="firstName">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" onblur="verificarForm()" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required="">
          <div id="blurName" class="invalid-feedback">
            Digite um nome válido.
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Script:**

```
function verificarForm(){
  var element = document.getElementById("blurName");
  if($("#firstName").val() == ''){
  element.classList.add("d-block");
  }else{
    element.classList.remove("d-block");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeira coisa é esquecer id's. Como um id deve ser único na página, não tem como manipular vários elementos com o mesmo id, como está fazendo na função na linha:

```
var element = document.getElementById("blurName");
```

E na linha:

```
if($("#firstName").val() == ''){
```

O que você precisa fazer é enviar para a função o elemento como parâmetro `this`, e lá na função pegar o próximo elemento do input que chamou a função e adicionar ou remover a classe `.d-block`. O método `.nextElementSibling` seleciona o elemento adjacente (adjacente: que vem logo após). O código fica extremamente simples e curto.

Embora esteja usando Bootstrap com jQuery, não é nem preciso usar o jQuery para isso, veja:

```js
function verificarForm(e){
  e.nextElementSibling.classList[!e.value ? 'add' : 'remove']("d-block");
}
```

```css
.invalid-feedback{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
   <label for="firstName">Nome</label>
   <input type="text" onblur="verificarForm(this)" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" required="">
   <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Digite um nome válido.
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
   <label for="firstName">Nome</label>
   <input type="text" onblur="verificarForm(this)" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" required="">
   <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Digite um nome válido.
   </div>
</div>
```

Aqui: `!e.value ? 'add' : 'remove'` usei um operador ternário que irá selecionar um dos dois métodos (`add` ou `remove`) de acordo com o valor do input (`!e.value`).

O `!e.value` retorna `true` se o campo estiver vazio e chama o método `add`, do contrário irá chamar o método `remove`.

Você pode, inclusive, utilizar o `.trim()` para evitar que o usuário só digite espaços no input e seja considerado válido, já que espaços também são caracteres:

```
!e.value.trim()
```

---

Com jQuery ficaria desta forma a função:

```
function verificarForm(e){
  $(e).next()[!e.value ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']("d-block");
}
```

O `.next()` do jQuery tem função similar ao `.nextElementSibling`.